# How to do I share Images to whatsupp and save image to device?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been doing this drawing app with kotlin and I have function to should enable to share the image via whatsapp etc. when image is saved. Although image is not saved in the actual real device but it is saved to storage/emulated/0/android/data/nameofpackage when using emulator instead real device and after that it opens the share and when I choose whatsapp for example it gives me toast saying sharing failed or when choosing gmail and there is no image shown there or attached.
This is my save button function:

```
        val ibSave : ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.ib_save)
        ibSave.setOnClickListener {
            if (isReadStorageAllowed()){
                showProgressDialog()
                lifecycleScope.launch{
                    val flDrawingView: FrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.fl_drawing_view_container)

                    saveBitmapFile(getBitmapFromView(flDrawingView))
                }
            }

        }
```

This is the saveBitmapFile function:

```
private suspend fun saveBitmapFile(mBitmap: Bitmap?): String{
        var result = ""
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            if(mBitmap != null){
                try {
                    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes)

                    val f = File(externalCacheDir?.absoluteFile.toString()
                            + File.separator + "KidsDrawingApp_"
                            + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".png")

                    val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
                    fo.close()

                    result = f.absolutePath

                    runOnUiThread{
                        cancelProgressDialog()
                        if(result.isNotEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                                "File saved successfully :$result",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            shareImage(result)
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,
                                "Something went wrong while saving the file.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    result = ""
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }

        return result
    }
```

This is my shareImage function:

```
    private fun shareImage(result: String){
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(result), null){
            path, uri ->
            val shareIntent = Intent()
            shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            shareIntent.type = "image/png"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"))
        }
    }
```

and this is my path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="captured"
        path="Android/data/com.test.kidsdrawingapp/files" />
</paths>
```

and my manifest as following added:

```
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.test.kidsdrawingapp.fileprovider"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/path"
                />
        </provider>
```

Comment: You can compress directly to the FileOutputStream. Do away with the ByteArrayOutputStream: mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 9⁰, fo);

Comment: You asked this before this week and did not react. And did not use FileProvider too.

Comment: What you mean asked before? This is first time I am asking about this? And I don't know how that answer helps my situation where the sharing doesn't work and image isn't saved to device.

Comment: The same code was posted a few days ago. So i wonder where you got it from. Same code same question. Same not using fileprovider. Sorry if it was not you.

Comment: But to give the same answer `path, uri ->` I think that uri is null. Check before use.

Comment: @blackapps I got the image sharing to work now. But I still have issue with images not being saved on my phone(real device) and when using emulator they are saved to the emulator device